# Image upload form doesn't work on the web

Tags: php, mysql, database, upload, xampp

I have a working HTML/PHP based site running on my local host (using XAMPP). But when I transferred it to a live server one part doesn't want to work.. The image upload. The database on localhost and live are almost identical. And all the other stuff using the database works fine. I'm only not able to upload images.

This is the code i use for the upload:

```
    <?php 
include 'includes/header.php';
    ?>
    <br /><br />
    <form action="image.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="image">
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>

    <?php


        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {

        include 'includes/connection.php';

        $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
        $imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
        $imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["type"]);

        if(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image")
        {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `blob` VALUES('','$imageName','$imageData' )");
            echo "Plaatje opgeslagen";
        }
        else{
            echo "alleen plaatjes";
        }
        }
        ?>      
</body>
```

I'm sorry it might seems sloppy for you guys! But I'm still learning :). To explain the code a little:

In the top is te form .

then we get the submit

the include connection is working because we have a connection with the database. Else we would not be able to be on the site.

The query needs to be inserted to the table called: 'blob' with the following fields: 'id', 'name', and 'image'.

So the strange thing is, it works on localhost but not live. I hope someone can help me. This was my first post on stackoverflow, if I did something wrong or unusual let me know I'm verry willing to learn! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried checking your PHP error logs?

Comment: Please check which version of PHP in live.

Comment: Go through `mysqli` or `PDO` because in `PHP 7` `mysql_*` was removed.

Answer (score 0):

The mysql_query() function was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0. A newer standard to look into is the PDO driver built into PHP.

Also CertaiN has the top post currently at http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

> You'd better check $_FILES structure and values throughly.
>   The following code cannot cause any errors absolutely.

Example:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

try {

// Undefined | Multiple Files | $_FILES Corruption Attack
// If this request falls under any of them, treat it invalid.
if (
    !isset($_FILES['upfile']['error']) ||
    is_array($_FILES['upfile']['error'])
) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Invalid parameters.');
}

// Check $_FILES['upfile']['error'] value.
switch ($_FILES['upfile']['error']) {
    case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
        break;
    case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
        throw new RuntimeException('No file sent.');
    case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
    case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
        throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
    default:
        throw new RuntimeException('Unknown errors.');
}

// You should also check filesize here. 
if ($_FILES['upfile']['size'] > 1000000) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
}

// DO NOT TRUST $_FILES['upfile']['mime'] VALUE !!
// Check MIME Type by yourself.
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
if (false === $ext = array_search(
    $finfo->file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']),
    array(
        'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
        'png' => 'image/png',
        'gif' => 'image/gif',
    ),
    true
)) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
}

// You should name it uniquely.
// DO NOT USE $_FILES['upfile']['name'] WITHOUT ANY VALIDATION !!
// On this example, obtain safe unique name from its binary data.
if (!move_uploaded_file(
    $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'],
    sprintf('./uploads/%s.%s',
        sha1_file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']),
        $ext
    )
)) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
}

echo 'File is uploaded successfully.';

} catch (RuntimeException $e) {

echo $e->getMessage();

}

?>
```

His code contributed is how I choose to validate and store files. Note that instead of storing the image on the database he uploads it to the server in a file named uploads/

You can then store this file path in the database column and retrieve it when needed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

- You might want to update to use mysqli or PDO_MYSQL as of PHP 7 mysql features are removed.
- Never trust form data (such as $_FILES["image"]["type"]) it is not reliable.
- May want to check image size so people are not uploading massive images into your database.

Try something more like this:

HTML:

```
<form action="image.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload: <input type="file" name="imageUpload" id="imageUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$imageTypes = ['png', 'jpg', 'gif'];
if($_POST["submit"] == 'Upload Image')
{
    $fileExt = pathinfo($_FILES['imageUpload']['tmp_name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(!in_array($fileExt, $imageTypes))
        throw new Exception("Invalid upload type we only accept: " . implode(", ", $imageTypes)).
    else
    {
        $imageStr = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['imageUpload']['tmp_name']));
        $imgName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"]);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `blob` VALUES('','$imgName','$imageStr' )");
    }
}
```

More about mysqli: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

More about PDO_MYSQL: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php